# Why is the movie titled "If I Stay"?

Tags: title, if-i-stay

I saw the movie, But I didn't find any resemblance between title's meaning to the plot of the movie.

Why is the movie titled "If I Stay" ?

Comment: Then you clearly missed **the whole premise of the movie**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [IMdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1355630/):

> Life changes in an instant for young Mia Hall after a car accident puts her in a coma. During an out-of-body experience, she must decide whether to wake up and live a life far different than she had imagined. The choice is hers if she can go on.

So, the main character is having an out of body near-death experience.  She has a choice to go back into her body and continue living, or not and properly die.

**If she stays,** the movie shows us what her life will be like going forward.  Hence the title, "*If I Stay.*"